# Different error mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sed

Posting again - one error was eradicated after I installed the MySQL driver 
but then this one occurred

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
    Communications lin failure. 
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
    The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

There are no problems during compilation only when the Add Button is clicked so here is the code for it:

```
package mainquiz;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class AddStudent extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public AddStudent() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NameText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    DateText = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    ProblemSolvingScoreText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    ComprehensionScoreText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    MemoryScoreText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    AveragePercentageText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    jLabel1.setText("Student Name");

    jLabel2.setText("Date of Quiz");

    jLabel3.setText("Score ");

    jLabel4.setText("Average Percentage");

    DateText.setColumns(8);
    try {
        DateText.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####")));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            DateTextKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    ProblemSolvingScoreText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            ProblemSolvingScoreTextKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    ComprehensionScoreText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            ComprehensionScoreTextKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    MemoryScoreText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            MemoryScoreTextKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    AveragePercentageText.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

    jButton1.setText("Add Student");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Rosewood Std Regular", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("Add Student");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(NameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ComprehensionScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(MemoryScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ProblemSolvingScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(DateText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 227, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(AveragePercentageText))))
            .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(74, 74, 74))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(NameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(DateText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(ProblemSolvingScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(ComprehensionScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 15, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(MemoryScoreText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(AveragePercentageText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(8, 8, 8))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void ProblemSolvingScoreTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                 
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)|| (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        tk.beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                                

private void ComprehensionScoreTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)|| (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        tk.beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                               

private void MemoryScoreTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)|| (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        tk.beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StudentScores";
        String username = "admin3";
        String password = "admin3";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String Query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME, DATEOFQUIZ, MEMORYSCORE, COMPREHENSIONSCORE, PROBLEMSOLVINGSCORE, AVERAGEPERCENTAGE) VALUES ('"+NameText.getText()+"','"+DateText.getValue()+"','"+MemoryScoreText.getText()+"','"+ComprehensionScoreText.getText()+"','"+ProblemSolvingScoreText.getText()+"', '"+AveragePercentageText.getText()+"')";

        stmt.execute(Query);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Added");

        NameText.setText(null);
        DateText.setText("00/00/0000");
        MemoryScoreText.setText(null);
        ComprehensionScoreText.setText(null);
        ProblemSolvingScoreText.setText(null);
        AveragePercentageText.setText(null);

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
}                                        

private void DateTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    char c= evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(c)|| (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)))
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        tk.beep();
        evt.consume();
    }    

}                                 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AddStudent().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField AveragePercentageText;
private javax.swing.JTextField ComprehensionScoreText;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField DateText;
private javax.swing.JTextField MemoryScoreText;
private javax.swing.JTextField NameText;
private javax.swing.JTextField ProblemSolvingScoreText;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Read somewhere that someone used this thing called "sed" to change their bind-address and that worked - any tips on how I could do that on Netbeans IDE? (I'm a newbie so please use simple terms)

Comment: When posting a stack trace, post the _complete_ trace (the whole thing, even if it's long) and format it as code (indent 4 spaces).  Also, identify the line in your code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Also, since this is probably a MySQL configuration problem, show us the MySQL configuration.

Comment: @JimGarrison copied and pasted everything

Comment: I'd like to help you but there just isn't enough information here.  What platform (WIndow/Linux/Other) are you on.  Is MySQL installed on the same machine or a different one?  Have you verified that MySQL is running correctly (i.e. can you connect with the command line client)? Are you sure the database name is `StudentScores`?

Comment: Windows 7, um Netbeans IDE is installed on this one and I just created a MySQL database through it so this one, i don't know how to connect with the command line client - looked something up, installed Putty, it's inactive :/ clicked on the database and clicked connect and got this "Mon Jan 04 00:40:41 GMT 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Jan 04 00:40:44 GMT 2016 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.3.2 - (1557835) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527", yep I copied that straight from the database name editor @JimGarrison

Comment: @JimGarrison I found where to view the stack trace :D! but there's nothing there it just says "Mon Jan 04 00:40:41 GMT 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy. "

Comment: Apache Derby is not MySQL -- they are completely different packages.  Before any progress can be made you need to determine definitively which database you are using.  If it's really Apachy Derby, then you need to ensure Derby is correctly installed AND running, and revert your connection URL back to the Derby version.

Answer (score -1):

> Your MySQL Server is not running for sure!

Start your MySQL Server first and then your app!!!!!

Comment: I don't know how to do that... i did connect to the database before i ran it

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using